# My netbeans thinks that the value which entered into the textfield is a column name and not the value which i need it to delete

Tags: java, jdbc

```
private void deleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    try {
        // String sql = "Delete from tender.bidder where b_id =" + bidtxt.getText();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("delete from tender.bidder where bidder.b_id =" + bidtxt.getText());
        int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.print(i + "record deleted");
        con.close();
        bidtxt.setText("");
        bnametxt.setText("");
        officetxt.setText("");
        streettxt.setText("");
        citytxt.setText("");
        statetxt.setText("");
        contacttxt.setText("");
        passwordtxt.setText("");
        emailtxt.setText("");
        tidtxt.setText("");
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    selectionall();

}
```

> The error : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'B001' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'B001' is not a column in the target table.

Comment: do ***not*** concatenate values into SQL strings. Learn how to properly use a `PreparedStatement` - as a side effect that error will go away as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the PreparedStatement properly. You would use a `?` where your values are supposed to be. However, you are also missing the quotes you need around the string in your statement which is causing your syntax error.

```
// Proper PreparedStatement example.
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM tender.bidder WHERE bidder.b_id = ?");
pstmt.setString(1, bidtxt.getText());
int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();

// String values need '' quotes.
Statement s = con.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM tender.bidder WHERE bidder.b_id = '"+bidtxt.getText()+"'");
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH MANN.THIS MEANS A LOT.SRSLY THO THANK YO MAN.